# sizeof() behaving differently between 32 bit and 64 bit processes

Tags: c++, g++

Consider the following program

```
#include<iostream>

struct SimpleStructure
{
    double obj;
};

struct Composite
{
    struct SimpleStructure u;
    char ch;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "sizeof(double)                 : " << sizeof(double) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(struct SimpleStructure) : " << sizeof(struct SimpleStructure) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(struct Composite)       : " << sizeof(struct Composite) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above with `g++ -m64 <filename>.cpp`, I get the following output

```
sizeof(double)                 : 8
sizeof(struct SimpleStructure) : 8
sizeof(struct Composite)       : 16
```

But the same code when I compile using `g++ -m32 <filename>.cpp`, I get the following output

```
sizeof(double)                 : 8
sizeof(struct SimpleStructure) : 8
sizeof(struct Composite)       : 12
```

Why is there a difference in the padding in the structure in a 32 bit and 64 bit process?

Comment: Hm, isn't that obvious? 64-bit pads to 64-bit (8 byte, 2*8 in that case) alignment, 32-bit to 32-bit (4 byte, 3*4 in that case) alignment

Comment: Why do you care? Let the compiler do its job.

Comment: You have alignment which might differ between 32/64.

Comment: @Ctx, AFAIK, the byte alignment/padding of the structure should correspond to the byte alignment of its strictest member i.e double in this case. "double" is 8 bytes both in 32 bit and 64 bit system.

Comment: @Bathsheba, I care because I want to understand why the compiler wants to do what it is doing.

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi But you do not have a double there, instead you have another structure (SimpleStructure). gcc obviously does not resolve that recursively. However, you are right that for most intel 32-bit processors it might be desirable to have double values aligned at 8-byte boundaries, there are usually compiler-specific ways to force that.

Comment: *"double" is 8 bytes both in 32 bit and 64 bit system* Size and alignment are different things. It's perfectly OK for `double` to be 8 bytes long and 4 byte aligned [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86).

Comment: @Ctx, I tried replacing SimpleStructure with double and the difference still exist.

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi -malign-double probably does what you expect

Comment: The answer is: because C++ does not guarantee the same alignment and padding between 32 and 64 bit architectures. And insofar as to why the alignment and padding has to be different, it's the same reason why water is wet and the sky is blue: because that's what it is. This is the compiler's worry to deal with. As far as the C++ code itself goes, it must be aware of the fact that it has no padding/alignment guarantees, and adjust its logic to accomodate that.

Comment: Don't change your question after you have received an answer.

Comment: Read about padding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding

Comment: By accident or otherwise, please don't change your question into a different question, after you have received an answer that answers your question. I have rolled back your edits again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a 32-bit platform `alignof(double) == 4`. See `man gcc`:

> ```
>   -malign-double
>   -mno-align-double
>        Control whether GCC aligns "double", "long double", and "long long"
>        variables on a two-word boundary or a one-word boundary.  Aligning
>        "double" variables on a two-word boundary produces code that runs
>        somewhat faster on a Pentium at the expense of more memory.
>        On x86-64, -malign-double is enabled by default.
>
>       Warning: if you use the -malign-double switch, structures
>        containing the above types are aligned differently than the
>        published application binary interface specifications for the
>        x86-32 and are not binary compatible with structures in code
>        compiled without that switch.
> ```

The size of a structure is a multiple of alignment of a member with the largest alignment requirement. Here, such a member is of type `double`, so `sizeof(struct Composite) == N * alignof(double)`.

Comment: thanks, loved your answer.. tested it as well. Just wanted another clarification. The above explanation seems consistent with g++ compiler with an exception of `long double`. In case 32 bit process, g++ seems to align `long double` to a 4 word boundary which is consistent with 64 bit process ( 64 bit process aligns `long double` in a 2 word boundary).

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi 64 and 32-bit are different ABIs with different requirements. On x86 Linux in 32-bit mode, `sizeof(long double)` is 12 and `alignof(long double)` is 4, for 64-bit mode they are 16 and 16.

Comment: OK, I get it. It is the ABI specification that defines the sizeof()/alignof and compilers conform to it by it by default lest they should be used in cross binary communication. We can change it at the cost of making it non conformant with the ABI specification.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the C standard is concerned, the compiler is free to choose any alignment. The following is a description on how the compilers I have used implemented alignment.

Often, the word size is chosen (32 bits on a 32 bit system, 64 bits on a 64 bit system) because it is usually an efficient choice in terms of tradeoff between memory usage and performance on the target platform. Usually the memory can be accessed in word-size chunks and the cpu instructions assumes that the data is aligned, so if the data is misaligned the cpu would need to access 2 chunks of memory and shift the data into alignment. This wastes valuable cpu cycles.

Entities smaller than the word size are aligned by their size. Word-sized and larger entities are aligned on word boundaries.

Structs members are aligned separately and then the entire struct is padded and aligned the same as its largest member.

The default alignment can often be overriden with pragmas. Please refer to the documentation for your compiler for details.

Example:

```
/* Override the default alignment and pack everything tight. */
#pragma pack(1)
```

Comment: There is no requirement on a C implementation to document its alignment requirements. However, if you consider `printf` family of functions, they all accept pointer arguments for `%n` conversion. Such a pointer must point to an object that is properly aligned, otherwise that would be UB. Hence, the compiler is not free to choose the alignment, no. It must adhere to the platform ABI.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Clarified the first sentence.

Comment: _Memory can be accessed in word-size chunks_ does not make much sense in this age. You may like to consult "§2.5.5.1 Efficient Handling of Alignment Hazards" in "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual".

Answer (score -1):

First, the sizes of integer types can vary between architectures. There is a nice table here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Second, pointers have different sizes depending on architecture. 32 bit machines have 32 bit pointers, and 64 bit machines have 64 bit pointers. If you are interested in older architectures, 8 bit machines had 16 bit pointers, and 16 bit machines had 32 bit pointers, though they worked weirdly on the 8086.

Finally, what's the case in your struct, is probably alignment. For efficiency reasons, varaibles are aligned to word boundaries, and word size may differ between architectures. See more information here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Alignment

Comment: I am aware of everything the you wrote. My confusion arouse when I replaced struct SimpleStructure u with char ch[5] and got identical answers for 32 bit and 64 bit processes.

Comment: @AbdusSalamKhazi Did you read the alignmeht link (and maybe more about alignment)? (You said you did, but apparently you have no idea of it)